# React, unable to access array in object

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am unable to access the object inside array ( dailyData). DailyData is an array on object in timesheet object.
I tried using dailyData object using .Map function but getting error.

My component:

```
  <Col>{timesheet.mainSite}</Col>
  <Col>{timesheet.createdBy}</Col>
  <Col>{timesheet.weekRange}</Col>

  {timesheet.dailyData.map((daily) => (
    <div textAlign="center" key={daily.dailyId}>
      <div>{daily.day}</div>
    </div>
  ))}
```

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAogB.png)

Json File:

```
{ "mainSite": "UOA",
    "weekRange": "25-5-2020 To 31-5-2020",
   
    "dailyData": [
        {
            "dailyId": 1,
            "day": "Monday",
            "tsheetId": 1,
           
        },
        {
            "dailyId": 14,
            "day": "Sunday",
           }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access map of undefined by looking at error snapshot.
This error usually occurs when you try to access the property of an object which is undefined.
In your case, this might happen that when your component renders for the first time, it is getting timesheet value undefined.
So basically to prevent this breaking your code you can add some defensive code like below.

```
 {timesheet && timesheet.dailyData && timesheet.dailyData.map((daily) => (
    <div textAlign="center" key={daily.dailyId}>
      <div>{daily.day}</div>
    </div>
  ))}
```

It simply prevents accessing any property of timesheet if timesheet itself undefined.
See more about logical AND - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

Comment: Thanks Sagar. I am seriously going to go through the link you shared. That really helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it looks like you have not put proper closing brackets in the JSON file.
Try this

```
{ 
    "mainSite": "UOA",
    "weekRange": "25-5-2020 To 31-5-2020",
    "dailyData": [
        {
            "dailyId": 1,
            "day": "Monday",
            "tsheetId": 1,
           
        },
        {
            "dailyId": 14,
            "day": "Sunday",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks but its not the issue. I missed that while posting here. I am able to access  value for mainSite, but unable to loop through dailyData.